# Computation of cross section in a electron+photon into electron+pion process (help with homework exercise)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

$\require{cancel}$
**Problem:**
I'm given the following U(1) gauge invariant lagrangian density:
$$\mathcal{L}={1\over{2}}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-{1\over{2}}m_\pi^2\phi^2+\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu{D_\mu}-m+\lambda\phi)\psi-{1\over{2}}F_\mu{_\nu}F^\mu{^\nu}-{1\over{2\xi}}{(\partial_\mu{A^\mu})}^2$$

and I'm asked to:

1. Draw all the possible diagrams at tree level that contribute to 2-->2 processes
2. Compute the nonpolarized cross section for the process:
   $$e^-\gamma\rightarrow{e^-}\pi$$ in the limit where the $e^-$ mass $m$ is negligible, but not the pion's $m_\pi$

**My Attempt**
For point 1, I would say that since the lagrangian contains both the QED and Yukawa like terms: $e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu{A_\mu}\psi,\space    \lambda\bar{\psi}\psi\phi$, the admissible diagrams are the ones with Yukawa vertices, QED vertices and diagrams with both.

For point 2, I drew the diagrams

[image]

and computed the amplitude as

$$M{_a}=(-i\lambda)(-ie)\bar{u}(p_2){(\cancel{q_1}+\cancel{q_2})\over{s-m^2}}u(q_1)\gamma^\mu\epsilon_{\mu}$$

and computed the amplitude as

$$M{_b}=(-i\lambda)(-ie)\bar{u}(p_2)\gamma^\mu{(\cancel{q_1}-\cancel{p_1})\over{t-m^2}}u(q_1)\epsilon_{\mu}(q_2)$$

which can be written collectively as
$$M=-(e\lambda)\epsilon_{\mu}(q_2)\bar{u}(p_2)\left[{{\cancel{q_1}+\cancel{q_2}+m}\over{s-m^2}}\gamma^{\mu}+\gamma^{\mu}{{\cancel{q_1}-\cancel{p_1}+m}\over{t-m^2}}\right]u(q_1)$$

or, concisely:
$$M=\bar{u}(p_2)\Gamma_\mu u(q_1)\epsilon_{\mu}(q_2)$$

For the squared amplitude I get:
$$|M|^2=(e\lambda)^2 \left(\bar{u}(q_1)\Gamma_{\mu} u(p_2)\right)  \left(\bar{u}(p_2)\Gamma_{\nu} u(q_1)\right)   \epsilon^{{*}\mu}(q_2) \epsilon^{\nu}(q_2)  $$

the exercise asks to take the unpolarized cross sections, so using the identity $\sum_{\lambda}{\epsilon^{{*}\mu}(k) \epsilon^{\nu}(k)}\rightarrow{-g_{\mu\nu}}$ I got the following

$${{1}\over{2}}\sum_{\text{spins}}\sum_{\lambda}{|M|^2}
={-g_{\mu\nu}\over{2}}tr(\cancel{q_1}+m)\Gamma^{\mu}(\cancel{p_2}+m)\Gamma^{\nu}
$$

**This is where I got stuck.**

First of all, even neglecting the electron mass, this trace contains multiple terms of 6 gamma matrices, which seems a bit too long to compute for an exercise.

Also, the exercise says that I cannot neglect $m_\pi$, which also is suspicious because In $M$ the scalar propagator for $\pi$ appears nowhere, and consequently there are no $m_{\pi}$

This makes me believe I did something wrong in computing the amplitude or in the diagrams, but I cannot find any problem with what I have done.

I wish you could tell me if I did everything right up to this point or if I messed up something

Comment: Your trace should encompass the entire expression, as you have it written you're only taking the trace of the first piece. But you should also have a spin sum over the pion wave functions and use of the completeness relation there.

Comment: 1. You can simplify your expression for the matrix element a bit by taking advantage of $(q_1 \! \! \! \!  / -m)u(q_1)=0$ (and analogously for $\bar{u}(p_2) p_2 \! \! \! \! /$). 2.In your expression for $|M|^2$, the first $\Gamma_\mu$ should be replaced by $\gamma^0 \Gamma_\mu^\dagger \gamma^0$.